# How can I make a report that does a group count based on a the first character of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [Romaji]       NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [EnglishAscii] AS               (ascii([English])) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

What I would like to do is to get a report that looks something like this:

```
A 25
B 35
C 10
D 99
...
Y 3
```

All the strings in the English column have a first character that is uppercase.

Can someone give me some hints as to how I can do this kind of a report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`LEFT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177601.aspx) string function

```
Select Left([English],1), Count(1)
From Yourtable
Group by Left([English],1)
```

or you can use [**`SUBSTRING`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) string function

```
Select Substring([English],1,1), Count(1)
From Yourtable
Group by Substring([English],1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UPPER` keyword in order to make the first character of the column [English] in to upper case ,if it is not.

```
SELECT UPPER(Left([English],1)) Col, 
       Count(1) CNT
FROM Yourtable
GROUP BY Left([English],1)
```

Comment: Use `UPPER(Left([English],1))` in `GORUP BY` also ;).

Answer (score 1):

Have a derived table which simply returns that first character. `GROUP BY` it's result:

```
select letter, count(*)
from
(
    select substring([English], 1, 1) as letter
    from [dbo].[Phrase]
) dt
group by letter
```

This way you only have to write the `substring` expression once. Easier to write without errors, and easier and safer to maintain/update.